# Field is not writeable: CaseMilestone.CompletionDate

Tags: case, casemilestone

I am running a trigger without sharing mode and I am getting this error

*Field is not writeable: CaseMilestone.CompletionDate*

I used this code in before trigger

```
cM.CompletionDate = System.now();
```

Can anybody help me out ?

Comment: You need to make sure you update the CaseMilestone before the case saves as closed. The milestone must already be closed when the case is closed. Use a before update trigger on your case, and make sure that you update your completion date prior to closing the case.

Comment: I am not closing Case

Comment: Been a while since I used them but isn't it just a case of marking it as completed and SF sets the date to now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the status of the milestone and the system will automatically set the completion date/time. You cannot write to this field.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code .. works like a charm ...

```
trigger CaseMileStoneTestJos on Case (after update) {

    Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (Case record : Trigger.new){
        caseIds.add(record.Id);
    }

    List<CaseMilestone> caseMilestones = [
        SELECT 
            Id
        FROM CaseMileStone
        WHERE CaseId IN :caseIds
    ];

    for (CaseMileStone cm : caseMilestones) {
        cm.CompletionDate = System.today();
    }

    update caseMilestones;
}
```

Comment: unless properly commented, please avoid posting code dumps as a solution. include reference links if possible alongside the essentials . Take some time to read [answer] and take the [tour] in order to get familiar with the forum. Thanks, and welcome to SFSE!